# Is there a way that can find one document and clone it with changing id/value in mongodb with Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

suppose I have code like this:

```golang
        var result bson.M
        err := coll.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&result)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        // somehow I can change the _id before I do insertOne
        if _, err := coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), result); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
```

is there a way I can insertOne without knowing the data struct? But I have to change the _id before I insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID field in MongoDB is always `_id`, so you may simply do:

```
result["_id"] = ... // Assign new ID value
```

Also please note that [`bson.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) is a map, and as such does not retain order. You may simply change only the ID and insert the clone, but field order may change. This usually isn't a problem.

If order is also important, use [`bson.D`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) instead of `bson.M` which retains order, but finding the `_id` is a little more complex: you have to use a loop as `bson.D` is not a map but a slice.

This is how it could look like when using `bson.D`:

```
var result bson.D
// Query...

// Change ID:
for i := range result {
    if result[i].Key == "_id" {
        result[i].Value = ... // new id value
        break
    }
}

// Now you can insert result
```